# Read a CSV file in python without using any imports at all?

Tags: python-3.x, list, read.csv

(Explaining in strong detail as I want to be as clear as possible)

I have a project to do and the very first task is as follows:

1. Open a given csv file
2. Read every line
3. All data separated by a comma
4. Take off all new line characters from the end of each row
5. RETURN each row as a list
6. "You may not use any imports for this task"

I believe the root of my issue is figuring out how to properly read this file as we are not allowed to use any imports and to my knowledge of endless research for solutions, this includes any and all modules and libraries etc.

My issue is that I need to *return* a singular row upon request but with the given test cases, my function only returns the first row no matter what is entered.
This is my current code:

```
def get_data(filename):
    """ Retrieves data from filename by returning every entry as a single list. """
    filename = "file.csv"
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf=8") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.split(',') # split elements between each comma (,)
            line[-1] = line[-1].strip() # Print the line without its final \n char
            return line
```

There are two test cases given to check if the code works:

`print(get_data("file.csv"[0])) # returns the headers` which should result in `['Timestamp', 'Arbitration_ID', 'DLC', 'Data', 'Class', 'SubClass']`
and
`print(get_data("file.csv"[10])) # returns 10th row` which should result in `['1597759710.128601', '453', '5', '00 88 8B 00 C1', 'Normal', 'Normal']`

Both of these test cases with my code print this:
`['Timestamp', 'Arbitration_ID', 'DLC', 'Data', 'Class', 'SubClass']`

Maybe I need to add a while loop or an if statement, I'm not sure, but every solution I've looked at includes imports and I cannot use them so I'm really stumped. Massive thank you in advance to anyone who understands the issue or can help me out at all.

Comment: This very likely means that your assignment is to write a **parser**, the CSV format is utterly complex if you want to handle all the subtleties of it so I doubt you have to be exhaustive (in particular since there is no consensus on the format), however I would expect that you need to handle basic functions such has **quoting/escaping**. Ask your instructor for detailed instructions and example input files. **Do not rely only on splitting on commas, this is likely incorrect** (`a,"a,b","1,2",3,4` should give [`'a', 'a,b', '1,2', 3, 4]`).

Comment: "my function only returns the first row no matter what is entered." *of course*. Because your for loop returns unconditionally in the body, so *you will have at max one iteration*.

Comment: You need to add code that creates a list and adds the individual lines (themselves now lists) to the list, then return that list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've created a new list and in my for loop I've written `new_list = [line] + new_list` and outside I have `return new_list` however it then just prints one massive nested list, rather than a single row. If I just have it has `new_list = line + new_list` nothing even manages to be output because the file is so large. Any further help?

Comment: For starters, `new_list = [line] + new_list ` is an inefficient way to append an item to a list, for that, you should use `new_list.append(line)`, then it will work fine for massive files (as long as you have memory available). And of course it returns a list, that's *precisely what the function is meant to do*: `""" Retrieves data from filename by returning every entry as a single list. """`